# I have fast so can I do this?

Tags: sawm, islamic-basis

I have fast so;

- Can I cut my nails?

  Can I cut my hairs?

My father said that I can do but I need more detailed answer or yes or no. Also some says that when you have fast your whole body is in fast so you can not cut any part of body such as nails otherwise my fast will be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard about it, either qur'an verse or hadeeth. I think you can cut your nails and hairs while fasting.

If there is any qur'an verse or hadeeth that mention about it. Please correct me.